# ¿Cómo recargar una tabla automáticamente al volver a la página que la contiene?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, datatables

Estoy usando `datatables` para mostrar ciertos datos; la función es la siguiente:

Uso un `select` que me lista los grupos de un colegio el cual al seleccionar el **GRUPO B** me hace un `CHANGE` y me arroja los datos en una tabla que tiene esta estructura:

`(nombre,apellido,numero_identificación,calificación,editar)`

En la columna `editar`, hay un botón que me redirige a una pestaña nueva, la cual ahí voy a editar los datos del estudiante que seleccione, principalmente la calificación.

**Problema:**

Lo que deseo es que cuando yo actualice la calificación *(Ej: si tenia calificación `BUENO` pues se actualizara a `EXCELENTE`)* cuando la cierre o vuelva a la pestaña donde esta la tabla automáticamente se actualice y no tenga que oprimir quizás un `F5` para tener que volver hacer un `select` y que me arroje los datos nuevamente actualizados.

Este es el código:

**Ajax select GRUPOS**

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'listar_grupos',
        type: 'POST'
    })
    .done(function(response)
    {
        var result = $.parseJSON(response);         
        for (var i = result.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
        {   
            var name= result[i].desc_group;
            $("#selecgrupo").append("<option value='" + result[i].id_group "'>" + name +  "</option>");
            $("#selecgrupo").selectpicker('refresh');
        }
    })  
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    });
```

**Ajax para mostrar la tabla de datos (CHANGE)**

```
listar_datos();
    function listar_students()
    {
        $("#table_students").change(function()
        {
            $.ajax({
                    url: 'listar_students',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {id_group:this.value}
                })
            .done(function(response)
            {
                var result= $.parseJSON(response);

                table_students.rows().remove();
                for (var i = result.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
                {
                    var rowNode = table_students
                    .row.add([
                                result[i].id_group,
                                result[i].stu_nombre,
                                result[i].stu_apellido,
                                result[i].stu_identificacion,
                                result[i].stu_calificacion,
                                '<center><button type="button" name="viewdata" id="viewdata" class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span></center></button>',
                            ])                     
                        .draw()
                    .node();
                }
            })
            .fail(function() {
                console.log("error");
            });
        });
    }
```

**Botón que me envía a la nueva pestaña, mostrándome los datos del estudianoe seleccionado.**

```
 $('#table_students tbody').on( 'click', '#viewdata', function ()
    { 
        event.preventDefault();     
        var data = table_students.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
        var id_group = data[0];
        window.open('../students/process_calificacion/' + id_group , '_blank');
    });
```

Comment: Revisa esta [respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40717063/4092887) o la [documentación de datatables](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()).

Answer (score 1):

Por qué mejor no abres el form de actualizar en una modal para que puedas compartir las funciones javascript en el dom?

La idea es que cuando termines de actualizar la información dar un refresh con código para que datatable vuelva a enviar una petición ajax y actualice los campos. Es necesario que vaya a hacer un select para actualizarlos, datatable no va a saber mágicamente qué pasó en una ventana con la que no interactúa.

También puedes habilitar la modificación de los datos directamente en el row con la API de datatable.

Comment: Es un buen aporte pero no lo hago ¿porque?, si, solamente voy a modificar las calificaciones pero aparte de eso hay una cantidad de datos externos que se relacionan para mostrar mas información necesaria sobre el estudiante, algo que en una modal se vería  mal.

Comment: Si cabe en una ventana nueva entonces cabe igual en un modal. Los modales no necesariamente tienen que ser más chicos que la ventana padre.
Cuál es la finalidad de que se abra en otra ventana y no simplemente reedireccione? Como te decía antes, no puedes ejecutar la función ajax sin que compartan el dom o sin que ajax reciba una respuesta. Es interesante lo que necesitas, seguiré atento a ver si alguien más tiene la respuesta.

Comment: opino igual que @user2930137 esa es la forma más sencilla, otra opción sería que la tabla que tienes abierta en la ventana principal (la página más bien) se recargue cada x tiempo pero lo veo poco práctivo. Mucho mejor un modal, pues es la opción óptima para lo que quieres hacer. Otra opción sería poner en el campo de la tabla un input y actualizar directo desde ahí y si quieres ver detalle abrirlo en una ventana nueva como hasta ahora pero solo con los detalles sin el formulario de edición.